# Aspire One 722 frequently starts with illuminated black screen (64 Bit)

Tags: aspire-one

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and now updated to 12.10 (64 Bit) on Acer Aspire One 722's in a whole class in school. At my own and some of the pupils computers we have boot problems: The computers start normally, since they stop with a "bright black" (screen is obviously turned on but black) screen. The only solution is to shut off power and re-boot (mostly for one more time, sometimes two or more times until it starts normally). 
I didn't install any third-party-graphics-drivers. Can anyone help me with my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem similar to yours. After an upgrate to 12.10 I couldn't see the login screen. The screen was only in purple color (like the unity theme) but I heared the login sound. There was no chance to do anything. After googleing today I got the tip the reset the boot options in the bios. There the first entry was the network boot option depending on the freezing bug of 11.10. Now the netbook boots from the ssd first and surprise, surprise, I could see the login screen and could login to the 12.10. Maybe you should check your boot options and move down the network boot option. I hope this will help you.